# onbeforeunload javascript calling backing bean method

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on a website using jsf and getting benefit of the the features of primefaces, while I am managing the idea of saving changes onbeforeunload I'd face a problem. 
I am using a javascript for onbeforeunload, in order to save changes done, before making refresh, back, or closing for browser, knowing that am using firefox browser, 
Here's my javascript code:

```
Window.onbeforeunload= handleOnClose();
Function handleOnClose(){
If(document.getElementById("MyForm:btnEdit").disabled== true {
If confirm("The page will close, Do you want to save changes?")
Save();
}
}
```

And I am calling the save method in the javascript from a backing bean, using:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="Save" actionListener="#{bean.save()}" />
```

The problem is that javascript is firing naturally, but the method responsible for saving is called only and only when closing browser but NOT CALLED WHEN MAKING BACK OR REFRESH !
Is there any idea or hint for this problem ?

Comment: Is there an ajax request? Is `Save` actually called? Are there any errors?

Comment: It's called only when browser in closed. otherwise, on back and refresh, is not called

Comment: So the client-side JavaScript `Save`-function is not called on back and refresh, not even if you click yes in the dialog? Try to add `onstart="console.log('save');"` to the remoteCommand and check if it is logged on back or refresh. And also check the Network-tab of your JavaScript-console and look if there is an ajax request going out or not when you are clicking back or refresh.

Comment: Thanks Mrs for your help :)
It's clear after adding console.log('save') and viewing javascript-Console that javascript is firing but same problem still.. >>> executing save method found in backing bean when closing browser, but not executed when making back or refresh, which is confusing thing.

Comment: Where did you learn to capitalize your Javascript code like that? It looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creat a synchronized ajax request within the onbeforeunload event.

```
Window.onbeforeunload= handleOnClose();
    Function handleOnClose(){
        If(document.getElementById("MyForm:btnEdit").disabled== true {
            If confirm("The page will close, Do you want to save changes?")
                Save();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/foo',
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: false,
                    timeout: 4000
                });
            }
        }
```

this will block the browser for a maximum of 4 seconds.